# Need to batch add characters to filenames using Powershell

Tags: powershell, filenames

I have a series of files all named something like:

PRT14_WD_14220000_1.jpg

I need to add two zeroes after the last underscore and before the number so it looks like PRT14_WD_14220000_001.jpg

I've tried"

```
(dir) | rename-Item -new { $_.name -replace '*_*_*_','*_*_*_00' }
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing to what you attempted would be this.  In regex, the wildcard is `.*`.  And the parentheses do grouping to refer to later with the dollar sign numbers.

```
dir *.jpg | rename-Item -new { $_.name -replace '(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_','$1_$2_$3_00' } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\users\admin\foo\PRT14_WD_14220000_1.jpg Destination: C:\users\admin\foo\PRT14_WD_14220000_001.jpg".
```

Ok, here's my take when you want the number with max two zeroes padding.  $num has to be an integer for the .tostring() method I want.

```
dir *.jpg | rename-item -newname { $a,$b,$c,$num = $_.basename -split '_'
  $num = [int]$num
  $a + '_' + $b + "_" + $c + '_' + $num.tostring('000') + '.jpg'
} -whatif
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. Follow up question, the end of my names always needs to be 3 characters. How would I handle this if my starting integer at the end is two digits? I would have some files with one digit and others with two. So if it starts as '_11.jpg' I will need it to be '_011.jpg', but if it was '_5.jpg' I would need it to be '_005.jpg'?

Comment: I would do it in a completely different way with -split and .tostring().  Could you add that to the question?

Answer (score 0):

the following presumes your last part of the `.BaseName` will always need two zeros added to it. what it does ...

- fakes getting the `fileinfo` object that you get from `Get-Item/Get-ChildItem`
  replace that with the appropriate cmdlet. [*grin*]
- splits the `.BaseName` into parts using the `_` as the split target
- adds two zeros to the final part from the above split
- merges the parts into a `$NewBaseName`
- gets the `.FullName` and replaces the original BaseName with the `$newBaseName`
- displays that new file name

you will still need to do your rename, but that is pretty direct. [*grin*]

here's the code ...

```
# fake getting a file info object
#    in real life, use Get-Item or Get-ChildItem
$FileInfo = [System.IO.FileInfo]'PRT14_WD_14220000_1.jpg'

$BNParts = $FileInfo.BaseName.Split('_')
$BNParts[-1] = '00{0}' -f $BNParts[-1]
$NewBasename = $BNParts -join '_'

$NewFileName = $FileInfo.FullName.Replace($FileInfo.BaseName, $NewBaseName)

$NewFileName
```

output = `D:\Data\Scripts\PRT14_WD_14220000_001.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

The **[`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operates on [regexes (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)**, not [wildcard expressons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) such as  `*` (by itself), which is what you're trying to use.

A conceptually more direct approach is to **focus the replacement on the *end* of the string:**

```
Get-ChildItem | # `dir` is a built-in alias for Get-ChildItem`
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)', '00$&' } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- `(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)` matches a nonempty run (`+`) of non-`_` chars. (`[^_]`) preceded by `_` (`(?<=_`) and followed by a literal `.` (`(?=\.)`), excluding both the preceding `_` and the following `.` from what is *captured* by the match (`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are non-capturing *look-around* assertions).

  - In short: This matches and captures the characters after the last `_` and before the start of the filename extension.
- `00$&` replaces what was matched with `00`, followed by what the match captured (`$&`).

---

In a follow-up comment you mention wanting to not just blindly insert `00`, but to **`0`-left-pad the number after the last `_` to 3 digits**, whatever the number may be.

In **PowerShell [Core] 6.1+**, this can be achieved as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $_.Name -replace '(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)', { $_.Value.PadLeft(3, '0') } 
  } -WhatIf
```

- The script block (`{ ... }`) as the replacement operand receives each match as a [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instance stored in automatic variable `$_`, whose `.Value` property contains the captured text.
- Calling `.PadLeft(3, '0')` on that captured text `0`-left-pads it to 3 digits and outputs the result, which replaces the regex match at hand.

A quick demonstration:

```
PS> 'PRT14_WD_14220000_1.jpg' -replace '(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)', { $_.Value.PadLeft(3, '0') }
PRT14_WD_14220000_001.jpg # Note how '_1.jpg' was replaced with '_001.jpg'
```

In **earlier PowerShell versions**, you must make direct use of the .NET `[regex]` type's [`.Replace()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_), which fundamentally works the same:

```
Get-ChildItem |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '(?<=_)[^_]+(?=\.)', { param($m) $m.Value.PadLeft(3, '0') }) 
  } -WhatIf
```